# Python - formatting output with varying numbers of spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, string-formatting, delimiter

I'm new to python and am struggling with finding a way to format output similar to the below into csv.

The following code runs an expect script that yields columns separated by varying numbers of spaces.

```
out = subprocess.check_output([get_script, "|", "grep Up"], shell=True
print out

1501        4122:1501           Mesh    1.2.3.4 Up     262075   261927
1502        4121:1502           Mesh    1.2.3.5 Up     262089   261552
1502        4122:1502           Spok    1.2.3.6 Up     262074   261784
701000703   4121:701000703      Mesh    1.2.3.7 Up     262081   261356
```

What I want is to remove all whitespace and add a "," separator.

`1501,4122:1501,Mesh,1.2.3.4,Up,262075,261927`
`1502,4121:1502,Mesh,1.2.3.5,Up,262089,261552`
`1502,4122:1502,Spok,1.2.3.6,Up,262074,261784`
`701000703,4121:701000703,Mesh,1.2.3.7,Up,262081,261356`

I can achieve this via awk with `awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1};1'` but am struggling to find a python equivalent.

Any guidance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible by using the `sub` function in the `re` (regex) library.

```
import re

table_str = """
1501        4122:1501           Mesh    1.2.3.4 Up     262075   261927
1502        4121:1502           Mesh    1.2.3.5 Up     262089   261552
1502        4122:1502           Spok    1.2.3.6 Up     262074   261784
701000703   4121:701000703      Mesh    1.2.3.7 Up     262081   261356
"""

re.sub(" +", ",", table_str)
```

The `" +"` string literal in the `sub` function does a greedy match on all whitespace.

Comment: Don't use `str` as variable's name.

Comment: What if some of the fields have embedded spaces?

Comment: Thanks I like this approach using regex. Works like a charm! In this particular case there are no embedded spaces to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Split each line on space and then join the result with a comma

```
# The commented out step is needed if out is not a list of lines already
# out=out.strip().split('\n')

for line in out:
    print ','.join(line.split())
```

Comment: Thanks! The piece in comments was what I was missing. out wasn't already a list of lines so the split()s and joins() I tried were giving unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `out` as follows:

```
import csv
import StringIO

out = """1501        4122:1501           Mesh    1.2.3.4 Up     262075   261927
1502        4121:1502           Mesh    1.2.3.5 Up     262089   261552
1502        4122:1502           Spok    1.2.3.6 Up     262074   261784
701000703   4121:701000703      Mesh    1.2.3.7 Up     262081   261356"""

csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(out), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerows(csv_input)
```

Giving you `output.csv` file containing:

```
1501,4122:1501,Mesh,1.2.3.4,Up,262075,261927
1502,4121:1502,Mesh,1.2.3.5,Up,262089,261552
1502,4122:1502,Spok,1.2.3.6,Up,262074,261784
701000703,4121:701000703,Mesh,1.2.3.7,Up,262081,261356
```

[`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html?highlight=stringio#module-StringIO) is used to make your `out` string appear as a file object for the `csv` module to use.

Tested using Python 2.7.9